# Limit number of characters in input field

Tags: jquery, html, webforms, jquery-validate

I want to use jquery to limit the number of characters in an editable div (or form input).

Comment: what's wrong with maxlength for a form input?

Comment: Have a look at this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867479/limiting-number-of-characters-in-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: @stivlo b/c its an editable div

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for input field you can use maxlength attribute. If you are looking for div, check the following,

```
        $(function() {

            $ ('#editable_div').keydown ( function (e) {
                //list of functional/control keys that you want to allow always
                var keys = [8, 9, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 27, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 45, 46, 144, 145];

                if( $.inArray(e.keyCode, keys) == -1) {
                    if (checkMaxLength (this.innerHTML, 15)) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                    }
                }
            });

            function checkMaxLength (text, max) {
                return (text.length >= max);
            }
        });

        <div id="editable_div" contentEditable="true" onclick="this.contentEditable='true';" >TEXT BEGIN:</div>
```

**Edit: you should rewrite the checkMaxLength function to ignore tabs and newline**

Comment: This doesn't take into account pastes that will set the content over the maximum length

Answer (score 51):

make use of `maxlength` in `input` tag

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" />
```

Comment: NICE MAN... not aware of maxlength command work for html 4 browsers..:)

Answer (score 22):

Maxlength attribute- for browser, that support this feature.
Javascript - for others.

```
<input class="test-input" type="text" maxlength="12" />
<script>
$('.test-input').unbind('keyup change input paste').bind('keyup change input paste',function(e){
    var $this = $(this);
    var val = $this.val();
    var valLength = val.length;
    var maxCount = $this.attr('maxlength');
    if(valLength>maxCount){
        $this.val($this.val().substring(0,maxCount));
    }
}); 
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tvpRT/

Comment: very nice, except you used an "input" instead of a div contenteditable :)

Comment: ...probably because not all browsers support content editable... Sergey's answer is the best one here :)

Comment: Shouldnt this be  `$this.val($this.val().substring(0,maxCount-1));` to account for substring starting at 0? Correct me if im wrong please. And yes, this is an old thread, but still read by people.

Answer (score 9):

This should work for you I think.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="myText" id="myText" data-maxlength="10" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#myText').keyup(validateMaxLength);

function validateMaxLength()
{
        var text = $(this).val();
        var maxlength = $(this).data('maxlength');

        if(maxlength > 0)  
        {
                $(this).val(text.substr(0, maxlength)); 
        }
}
```

Comment: nice original one! :)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to make use of JQuery you can write something  yourself or just use an existing plugin such as [this one](http://unwrongest.com/projects/limit/).

But I agree with dku.rajkumar... What is wrong with using the `maxlength` attribute?

```
<input type="text" maxlength="15" />
```

If you're the biggest JQuery fan **ever** though and desperately want to set a `maxlength` to all of the input fields at once do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="text"]').attr({ maxLength : 15 });
});
```

Just keep in mind though that this method (the JQuery one) will not work for people who have (for any reason whatsoever) JavaScript disabled. While the `maxlength` attribute of the `input` tag works for everybody on all browsers.

Answer (score 4):

Let's say it is form input.
you can do it with 'maxlength' attribute but if you say 'using jQuery',
here's the solution.

```
$('input#limited').attr('maxlength', '3');
```

or you can check every keypress

```
$('input#limited').keypress(function() {
     /*
     check for 3 or greater than 3 characters.
     If you check for only greater than 3, then it will let
     you write the fourth character because just before writing,
     it is not greater than three.
     */
     if($(this).val().length >= 3) {
        $(this).val($(this).val().slice(0, 3));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#id').keypress(function(e) {
   var foo = $(this).val()
   if (foo.length >= 14) { //specify text limit
     return false;
   }
   return true;
});
```

Comment: What exactly is the point in returning either `true` or `false`? Why should one use JS for this if the browser supports other ways?

Comment: after 14 characters that returns false, afterwards user can't input value. js is a convenient way to this.

Answer (score 0):

just use attribute called "maxlength". You can read more about input's attributes at [w3 input](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/INPUT.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" maxlength="20" id="alert_title"/>
```

```
$('#alert_title').unbind('keyup change input paste').bind('keyup change input paste',function(e){       
        var $this = $(this);

        var val = $this.val();
        var valLength = val.length;
        var maxCount = $this.attr('maxlength');
        if(typeof maxCount == "undefined"){
            $this.attr('maxlength',100);
        }
        if(valLength>maxCount){
            $this.val($this.val().substring(0,maxCount));
        }
    });
```