# how can I code so that only one letter can be used in a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, json, textarea

I have a div and inside the div there is a textarea. But The problem is that I only want that when I will put in a word/letter I want to do so I only can put in like "1" or "A" and not "AA" or "11". Anyone got a code?

Comment: What language are you talking about? Can you show some code, please?

Comment: Im sorry. This is the first time im using this website. But I got help from Rayon. I just needed to put in "maxlength="" in my html file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Use `maxlength` attribute

```html
<textarea cols="30" rows="10" maxlength='1'></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you! for the help!

Answer (score -1):

In this thread you can find more options like jQuery validation: [Limit number of characters in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669268/limit-number-of-characters-in-input-field)

If you need also to check at backend, then in e.g. php it will be like:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['textfiledname']) && (strlen($_REQUEST['textfiledname'])     == 1) {
return true;
}
else {
return false;
}

?>
```