# jQuery allow selected characters only keypress function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I tried to use this code to limit user's input. A problem is I cannot use my return key or the enter in my keyboard in the input box. How can I solve my problem.
Im using this code:

```
$("input").keypress( function(e) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if ("bcdegkmnqupvxy36789".indexOf(chr) < 0)
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem? You want to use the enter key specifically for this? `function (e) { if (e.which === 13) stuff(); }` might help.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669268/limit-number-of-characters-in-input-field

Comment: What about mouse input,..eg. right click paste?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you need you can simply add another condition to the `if` statement which checks for the Return keycode: `13`:

```js
$("input").keypress(function(e) {
  var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  if ("bcdegkmnqupvxy36789".indexOf(chr) < 0 && e.which != 13)
    return false;
   
  console.log('allowed');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="foo" />
```

Comment: You didn't mention tab in the question, but that's keycode `9`. You need to add that (and any other keys you want to enable) to the `if` statement as well

Comment: I was making a point that manually entering all the allowed keys (like tab, shift, backspace) is a bad way of doing it. You only want to potentially prevent the default from occurring when the user strikes a key that has a character attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your if condition to allow `e.which === 13` (which is the Enter key) as follows:

```js
$("input").keypress( function(e) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    if ("bcdegkmnqupvxy36789".indexOf(chr) < 0 && e.which !== 13) {
        return false;
    }

    console.log( e.which, chr, 'allowed' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to limit the input if the user has entered a character and not hit one of the non-character entering keys (like tab, of return/enter).

So check to see if `chr` is not false-y (e.g. an empty string) first:

```
$("input").keypress( function(e) {
    var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    //if chr is a non-character keycode (like 13) then you won't return false
    if (chr && "bcdegkmnqupvxy36789".indexOf(chr) < 0)
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").keypress( function(e) {
var chr = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
if ("bcdegkmnqupvxy36789".indexOf(chr) < 0 && e.which !=13 && e.which !=8) 
    return false;
});
```