# Character Limit on Editable Div

Tags: iphone, ios, html, nsstring

I am trying to add character limitation on this editable div. What's the best approach I should follow?

```
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>img{height:30px; width:auto;}</style></head><body style=\"background-color: transparent; padding:0; margin:0; background-image:url('%@'); background-repeat: no-repeat;\" ><div id=\"edit\" style=\"padding-top:50px; height:270px; padding-bottom:50px; padding-left:20px; padding-right:20px; \"> <div id=\"editable\" autofocus contenteditable=\"true\" style=\"font-size:25px; overflow:scroll; display:block; height:240px; \"></div></div></body></html>", imageURL];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use java script with webview using,

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"your script"];
```

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867479/limiting-number-of-characters-in-a-contenteditable-div) helpful in restricting number of characters in editable div.