# Determine if JavaScript e.keyCode is a printable (non-control) character

Tags: javascript, keycode

I'd just like to know the range(s) of JavaScript `keyCode`s that correspond to typeable characters; or alternatively, the range of non-typeable (control) characters like backspace, escape, command, shift, etc. so I can ignore them.

The reason I ask is calling `String.fromCharCode()` is resulting in odd characters for control keys. For example I get "[" for left command, "%" for left arrow. Weirdness like that.

Comment: You don't think I googled it first? Come on. Did you even check those results or just assume I'm an idiot?

Comment: The word you are looking for is *printable*, most likely. Also, it seems `keyCode` is [system and implementation-dependent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/KeyboardEvent#Key_values), which only traduces to problems

Comment: Do you mean "printable"? Surely by definition every key code is "typeable"...

Comment: Sure, printable. I'm thinking "typeable" in the sense of it resulting in something typed, as opposed to just pressing a key that has some effect.

Comment: I'm sure somebody has already done this. Why a) waste time, and b) increase the possibility of error?

Comment: You can test the typed char with regex to verify if it matches the Character classes needed

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Keydown will give you the keyCode of the key pressed, without any modifications.

```
$("#keypresser").keydown(function(e){
    var keycode = e.keyCode;

    var valid = 
        (keycode > 47 && keycode < 58)   || // number keys
        keycode == 32 || keycode == 13   || // spacebar & return key(s) (if you want to allow carriage returns)
        (keycode > 64 && keycode < 91)   || // letter keys
        (keycode > 95 && keycode < 112)  || // numpad keys
        (keycode > 185 && keycode < 193) || // ;=,-./` (in order)
        (keycode > 218 && keycode < 223);   // [\]' (in order)

    return valid;
});
```

Only the number keys, letter keys, and spacebar will have keycodes correlating to `String.fromCharCode` as it uses Unicode values.

Keypress will be the charCode representation of the text entered. Note that this event won't fire if no text is "printed" as a result of the keypress.

```
$("#keypresser").keypress(function(e){
    var charcode = e.charCode;
    var char = String.fromCharCode(charcode);
    console.log(char);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LZs2D/1/ Will demonstrate how these work.

KeyUp behaves similarly to KeyDown.

Comment: Many characters are missed e.g. `,` or `%`

Comment: @AlexanderElgin Comma is there, keycode 190.  % is the same as 5, keycode 52, with the shift key pressed.

Comment: You should also check `e.ctrlKey === e.altKey`, because if precisely one of them is pressed then it is hotkey

Comment: Does the first solution work well internationally? Also wouldn't it be better to check for non-valid keys?

Comment: ctrlKey and altKey properites should be considered too as the "output" character might not be anything printable

Comment: @QuentinEngles - I'm almost positive that it does not work internationally: http://daniel-hug.github.io/characters/#k_49

Comment: @William Thanks. That makes me wonder what the international solution would be. Probably much more complicated. Something using utf8 maybe.

Comment: if (typeof evt.which === 'undefined') {
    // This is IE, which only fires keypress events for printable keys
    return true
    }

      // filter out backspace and ctrl/alt/meta key combinations

      if (evt.ctrlKey || evt.metaKey || evt.altKey || evt.which === 8) return false

Comment: Sadly, keyPress is getting deprecated

Answer (score 25):

I noticed that all characters with length of 1 ('A','B',number,symbol) is printable
so I use only. 
I use this solution for non-english characters too:

```
if(e.key.length==1)
    print();
```

Comment: I frowned when looking at this answer as it seems to simple to work... And yet. It seems to be just what the doctor ordered!

Comment: I realized the same and was going to post to SO and saw someone thought of it already (of course). Strangely simple and yet not widely posted. Hopefully I don't find out why in some negative edge case sometime in the future. As for now, it seems to work great!

Comment: This is almost 100% true (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values has a list of non-character keys, all of which are >1 character long), but isn't totally true for non-latin languages. JS strings don't do unicode well (https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) and for some single inputtable printable unicode chars, `key.length` will be >1. This should work correctly if you do `[...e.key].length` though, to count characters explicitly.

Comment: Oh also: in most cases you want to ignore events where ctrl/alt/meta are pressed too - Ctrl+C does not input a printable character even though `c` is printable.

Answer (score 23):

Just for background, the "keypress" event will give you a *charCode* property whenever you press a character key.

```
Editor.addEventListener('keypress', function(event){
    if (event.charCode) {
        //// character key
        console.log( String.fromCharCode(event.charCode) ); /// convert charCode to intended character.
    } else {
        //// control key
    }
```

However, the "keypress" event doesn't capture every keystroke - several keys fire before the "keypress" event.

In contrast, the "keydown" event will capture every keystroke, but it doesn't have a *charCode* property. So how can we tell if it's a character key? Checking on every key stroke whether the *keyCode* is within the lower and upper bounds for multiple ranges isn't optimally efficient. I suspect that there are also issues for characters outside of the ASCII range.

My approach is the check the length of the event "key" property. The "key" property is an alternative to "keyCode" to determine which key was pressed. For **control** keys, the "key" property is **descriptive** (e.g. "rightArrow", "F12", "return", etc.). For **character** keys, the "key" property for a character key is **just the character** (e.g "a", "A", "~", "\", etc.). Therefore, for every character key, the length of the "key" property will have length of 1; whereas control characters will have length greater than 1.

```
Editor.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if (event.key.length == 1){ 
        //// character key
    } else {
        //// control key
    }
})
```

Comment: That would have been brilliant but according to w3schools, Safari does not support it: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_key.asp

Comment: In my testing, Chrome does not appear to support this

Comment: Robbert is right that Safari is still the only browser that doesn't support it - it works on Chrome for me. That's weird that it's not working for you gillonba. I am genuinely curious, so I just want to check that you are using the 'keydown' event instead of 'keypress'. The 'keypress' event won't have a 'key' property for control characters.

Answer (score 4):

This article has a list of the `keyCodes` in `Javascript`:

http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Comment: Saw that, but it's not a complete list.

Comment: What do you classify as typeable characters?

Comment: A key that results in a character being added to a text field if typed, as opposed to things like backspace, left arrow, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RegEx for this:

```
$(".input").keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.key.match(/^[\d\w]$/i)) {
      // put function to trigger when a digit or a word character is pressed here
    }
```

the `i` flag makes the expression case insensitive.

Comment: It doesn't work like that. The character ^ has the key value "Dead" for combining characters.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2021, an easy way to do this is, through [`InputEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/InputEvent)'s.

This only works for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`, which should be the majority of cases:

```
function handleInput(event) {
  if (event.inputType === 'insertText' || event.inputType === 'insertCompositionText') {
    console.log('Input Detected', event.data)
  }
}

element.oninput = handleInput
// or
element.addEventListener('input', handleInput)
```

The `insertCompositionText` property allows us to detect some [precomposed characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character).

For tags other than `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`, we can use `keydown` event with `event.key.length` with the fixes mentioned by Tim Perry:

```js
function handleKeydown(event) {
  if([...event.key].length === 1 && !event.ctrlKey && !event.metaKey) {
    console.log('Key Detected', event.key)
  }
}
element.onkeydown = handleKeydown
// or
element.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeydown)
```

Despite this, I believe both struggle when it comes to recognising some precomposed characters and other quirks.