# Contenteditable div or span that resizes until it hits max length?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to have a contenteditable div in the browser that has maxlength - and it auto resizes until it hits the max length ?

Basically I want to have a editable elements that actually only consumes as much space as it is required to get displayed yet having the max length property .

```
EDITABLE_____________NORMAL WORD
```

I would like to make sure editalbe resize and only consumes as much as required .
Reason is that I want to generate PDF out of this . So the extra spaces will be trimmed any way . So in browser too we should see the same. It is too complex to solve ?

```
EDITABLE NORMAL WORD
```

A related question I found .

[Limiting Number of Characters in a ContentEditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867479/limiting-number-of-characters-in-a-contenteditable-div)

Comment: Your `div` must have css `height` or `max-height` set with an `overflow:scroll` or similar set because a div will automatically grow in height from the content without these set.

Comment: if you are referring to 'width' add css 'inline-block' to the div, to auto grow in width until it hits it's `max-width` css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the `contentEditable` fit neatly you simply need it to be an non-block-level element or set it to be such in CSS:

```
.textfield {display:inline;}
```

To limit the amount of characters that can be entered requires JavaScript...

First update your contenteditable element/s to include a `max` attribute:

```
<div contenteditable="true" name="choice1" class="textfield" max="15">EDITABLE</div>
```

Then use JS to listen for key-presses on these elements and only allow them until the max-length has been reached:

```
var textfields = document.getElementsByClassName("textfield"); 
for(i=0; i<textfields.length; i++){
    textfields[i].addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
        if(this.innerHTML.length >= this.getAttribute("max")){
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    }, false);
}
```

[Here's the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6mF5x/)

UPDATE: It's fairly trivial to extend this to include a `min` length too. [Here's an updated jsFiddle that does just that.](http://jsfiddle.net/6mF5x/2/)

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/KmFL6/ seems to work .

```
<strong>
    <p>Hello
<span class="editable" contenteditable=true placeholder="Element">   </span>World
    </p>
</strong>
```

Span being the key idea there . Span just spans across the area needed !

http://codepen.io/flesler/pen/AEIFc also is cool . 
CSS Property will give you a placeholder too .

```
[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can set the css to have `max-width` and `min-width` like so:

```
<style>
    .some-selector{
       max-width: 20em; /* or whatever you want */
       min-width: 0px;  /* this is only if it is empty */
       width:auto; 
       word-wrap: break-word /* useful if you have really long words that would overflow otherwise*/
    }
</style>
```

then in html as others are saying

```
<span contenteditable='true' class="some-selector"></span>
```

Comment: missing the . on the style selector name

Answer (score 1):

1. Create contenteditable common css sizing (flex, etc)
2. Set contenteditable css: `word-break: break-all` OR `break-word`