# jQuery/javascript | limit Characters in contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have done many tries but i am not sure why this is so buggy.
I know limiting question is being asked before. and i have implemented the solution for there solution.

but that solution seems buggy.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867479/limiting-number-of-characters-in-a-contenteditable-div
```

actually it works but sometimes it sends the total amount in the ajax post..

[image]

if you see the ajax post in below pic.

[image]

you can see it is posting unusual character..

How ever i have tried to put limit to only 2 characters??

Here is the Code Below.

```
var sum=0;
        //Now Need to Get Available Months on Based of Year
        $('tr.tableRow td.inner').on('click',function(e){
//            e.preventDefault();
//            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $(this).attr('contentEditable','true');
            $(this).addClass('inputCopyCat');
            $(this).focus();
            var lastColumnTotal = $(this).parent().find('.totalTD').text();
            var lastColumnSelector = $(this).parent().find('.totalTD');
//            console.log(lastColumn);
            max = 1;
            sum = Number(lastColumnTotal) - Number($(this).text());
            var editorSelector = $(this);
            editorSelector.keyup(function(e){
                $tr=$(this).closest('tr');
                $tr.find('td.inner').each(function(){
                    //console.log(Number($(this).text()));
                    sum += Number($(this).text());
                });
                //$tr.find('td.inner:last-child').text(sum);
                check_charcount(editorSelector, max, e);
            });
            editorSelector.keydown(function(e){ check_charcount(editorSelector, max, e); });

            function check_charcount(editorSelector, max, e)
            {
                if(e.which != 8 && editorSelector.text().length > max)
                {
                    // $('#'+content_id).text($('#'+content_id).text().substring(0, max));
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    Parexons.notification('You can Not Add More Characters','warning');
                }
            }
        });
        $('tr.tableRow td.inner').focusout(function(e){
//            e.preventDefault();
//            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            $('td.inputCopyCat').removeAttr('contentEditable');
            $('td.inputCopyCat').removeClass('inputCopyCat');
            var hoursWorked = Number($(this).text());
            var dateOfHoursWorked = $(this).attr('td-data');
            var projectID = $( 'td:first-child', $( this ).parents ( 'tr' ) ).attr('data-project');
            var lastColumnSelector = $(this).parent().find('.totalTD');
            console.log(hoursWorked);
            var postData = {
              hoursWorked: hoursWorked,
                dateOfHoursWorked: dateOfHoursWorked,
              projectID: projectID
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>leave_attendance/updateTimeSheetInfo",
                data: postData,
                type: "POST",
                success:function(output){
                    var data = output.split("::");
                    if(data[0] === "OK"){
                        Parexons.notification(data[1],data[2]);
                        //Now Need to Sum The Values in the Total if Record Return is Success...
                        totalSum = sum + Number(hoursWorked);
                        //console.log(sum);
                        lastColumnSelector.html(sum);
                    }else if(data[1] === "FAIL"){
                        Parexons.notification(data[1],data[2]);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

I have tried to create the same fiddle but i couldnt find this problem in fiddle thou the JQuery Code is same.?? its really confusing.
i mean locally it also do works but sometimes send the unusual character even thou there is a limit. but on jsFiddle it seemed fine to me. and code is almost same.

**[JS FIDDLE LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yhjw23of/11/)**

Is there any way to fix the problem locally??

Comment: why not use simple text input?

Comment: its a table td.. how to use input inside table td when pressed and when focus is out remove input. but thats not the question, even on text input i would have to use limit.

Comment: _and code is almost same_ The problem may lie exactly on the differences.