# Limit length of characters in htm in javascript

Tags: javascript, character, limit, octobercms

I have question. I used editable plugin in `octobercms` project. I can't find this in documentation. How can I limit the length of the characters in my content in html. If there is no any way so how can I do this with `JavaScript`? I tried to use code like this but I am low in `JavaScript`.

```
var x = document.getElementById('gallery');
  var tekst= x.outerText;
  console.log(tekst);
  console.log(x.outerText.length);
  if (x.outerText.length > 150) {

  var trimmedString = tekst.substring(0, 150);
 document.getElementById('gallery').outerText = trimmedString;
  }
```

But now this text not use dic and classes and editable. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: `How can i limit length of characters in my content in htm` ... less keystrokes when you're creating the html?

Comment: what about substring ?

Comment: this is not htlm its htm and i can edit this htm with plugin https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-editable

Comment: Maybe something in here is useful to you. https://octobercms.com/forum/post/override-maxlength255-attribute-in-backend-on-input-fields?page=1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do it in the HTML instead.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Username: <input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_maxlength.asp

Comment: Alternatively, check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867479/limiting-number-of-characters-in-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: this is not input this is document which i can editable with plugin

Answer (score 0):

you can just put `maxlength="10"` for maxlength it will stop the cursor for input after 10 characters.

Comment: this file has only <p>Some text</p> and i can edit this from plugin