# How to limit character count on contenteditible div in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I want to limit the character count in my contenteditible div in vanilla JavaScript.  I followed this post. But when the character limit is reached - you then can't delete the letters and start typing again. Please can anyone advise how to amend this code and explain why that is happening?

[Javascript - How to limit character in a contentEditable div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65834820/javascript-how-to-limit-character-in-a-contenteditable-div)

It's for a website where you can play with the type in the box so I want it to be easily editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `currentChars` with  the `length` of the target element text content with `currentChars = event.target.textContent.length` with each key press.

```js
let maxChars = 10;
let currentChars = 0;

function checkLength(event) {
  currentChars = event.target.textContent.length
  if(currentChars >= maxChars) {
    alert('reached max chars');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```css
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" onkeypress="checkLength(event)"></div>
<span></span>
```